# Multiple SQL jointure

Tags: sql, left-join

I will try to be the most intelligible possible as I'm a very beginner in SQL.

Here is my issue, I have a database with answers from questionnaries.

Each database have a user.id, unique.id, date, final score. And I would like to extract those data with a simple table which group the score of each questionnary by user.id and by date.

I have tried this :

```
SELECT A.user_id, SUBSTRING(A.created_at,1,10), A.SCORE, B.SCORE,
       C.SCORE, D.SCORE, E.SCORE
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B
    ON A.user_id = A.user_id AND SUBSTRING(A.created_at,1,10) = SUBSTRING(B.created_at,1,10)  
LEFT JOIN C
    ON A.user_id = C.user_id AND SUBSTRING(A.created_at,1,10) = SUBSTRING(C.created_at,1,10)
LEFT JOIN D
    ON A.user_id = D.user_id AND SUBSTRING(A.created_at,1,10) = SUBSTRING(D.created_at,1,10)
LEFT JOIN E
    ON A.user_id = E.user_id AND SUBSTRING(A.created_at,1,10) = SUBSTRING(E.created_at,1,10)
```

This is almost successful but I find out if some one did not participate to the A questionnary then I don't have anything about it.

I hope, I have been clear enough.

Thank you all,

Comment: Is it just a typo or should the `LEFT JOIN B ON A.user_id = A.user_id` say `A=B` instead of  `A=A`

Comment: I seems like you have several very similar tables. How come you can't store the same kind of data in one single table?

Comment: What's the created_at data type? Are you storing dates in a character column?!?

Comment: Most databases have [types for dates and times](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html) and [functions to work with them](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html). This is greatly preferable to using strings.

Comment: Why are you using string operations on what is described as a `date`?  Also tag with the database you are using.  Sample data and desired results would also help.

Answer (score 1):

You must manage your query with USER table (if you have it), as follow:

```
SELECT U.user_id, SUBSTRING(A.created_at,1,10), A.SCORE, B.SCORE,
   C.SCORE, D.SCORE, E.SCORE
FROM USER U
LEFT JOIN A
    ON U.user_id = A.user_id AND SUBSTRING(U.created_at,1,10) = SUBSTRING(A.created_at,1,10)  
LEFT JOIN B
    ON U.user_id = B.user_id AND SUBSTRING(U.created_at,1,10) = SUBSTRING(B.created_at,1,10)  
LEFT JOIN C
    ON U.user_id = C.user_id AND SUBSTRING(U.created_at,1,10) = SUBSTRING(C.created_at,1,10)
LEFT JOIN D
    ON U.user_id = D.user_id AND SUBSTRING(U.created_at,1,10) = SUBSTRING(D.created_at,1,10)
LEFT JOIN E
    ON U.user_id = E.user_id AND SUBSTRING(U.created_at,1,10) = SUBSTRING(E.created_at,1,10)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest two things, depending on how restricted you are to modify your tables.

1. Just use one table. Add a column `testType` or something like this. You can ever foreign key it and use only the keys there. That would make the recordset smaller.
   Then put all your results in that one table with the matching keys.
2. Use `UNION` if the tables are all the same and have just different entries, then query this union.

There is no need for a `JOIN` in your case, it's better to adapt the structure.
Otherwise you can try `FULL JOIN` to keep all the data.